# Given two uniformly distributed random variables, find the expected value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, expectation

X and Y are independent random variables that are both uniformly distributed on the interval [0,1]. Find $$E[Y\,|\,X<Y^2]$$
How would I go about setting this up with the given condition? I am completely stuck on this.

Answer (score 1):

In general $E\left[f\left(X,Y\right)\mid\left(X,Y\right)\in S\right]=\frac{\int_{S}f\left(x,y\right)dP\left(x,y\right)}{\int_{S}dP\left(x,y\right)}$

Here the denominator can be recognized as $P\left[\left(X,Y\right)\in S\right]$.

Applying that in this case leads to: $E\left[Y\mid X<Y^{2}\right]=\frac{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y^{2}}ydxdy}{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y^{2}}dxdy}=\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: Could you explain what the notation $dP(x,y)$ means? I haven't come across it before in my studies.

Comment: If you are working with real valued random variables $X,Y$ you can read it as $dF\left(x,y\right)$ where $F\left(x,y\right)$ is the common distribution function. In fact it is a more general notation that can also be applied if the random variables are not real-valued. There is no need for you to bother about it. Often you can write $dF\left(x,y\right)=f\left(x,y\right)dxdy$ where
$f$ denotes the density. In your case $f\left(x,y\right)=1$ if $x,y\in\left[0,1\right]$
and $f\left(x,y\right)=0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

For every $y$ in $(0,1)$, $P[X\lt y]=y$, hence $P[X\lt Y^k\mid Y]=Y^k$. This implies:

- $E[Y^n;X\lt Y^k]=E[Y^nP[X\lt Y^k\mid Y]]=E[Y^{n+k}]$.
- The $n=0$ case reads $P[X\lt Y^k]=E[Y^k]$.

Hence, $$E[Y^n\mid X\lt Y^k]=\dfrac{E[Y^{n+k}]}{E[Y^k]}. 
$$
Finally, $E[Y^i]=\dfrac1{i+1}$ for every $i\gt-1$, hence $E[Y^n\mid X\lt Y^k]=\dfrac{k+1}{k+n+1}$.